Encoder Decoder Transformer model generate a repetitive token as output in text summarization
I implemented a transformer Encoder Decoder (Bert2Bert) for text summarization task. In train phase train loss decreases but in prediction phase it generate a repetitive token as output for example [2,2,2,2,.....]. what should I do?
class BERT2BERT(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder_model_name='HooshvareLab/bert-base-parsbert-uncased', decoder_model_name='HooshvareLab/bert-base-parsbert-uncased',tokenizer=None,vocab_size=0):
        super(BERT2BERT, self).__init__()
        self.vocab_size=vocab_size
        # Encoder: ParsBERT transformer layers
        self.encoder = BertModel.from_pretrained(encoder_model_name)

        # Decoder: ParsBERT transformer layers with modifications
        decoder_config = BertConfig.from_pretrained(decoder_model_name)
        decoder_config.is_decoder = True  # Enable cross-attention
        decoder_config.add_cross_attention = True
        decoder_config.decoder_start_token_id=tokenizer.cls_token_id
        self.decoder = BertModel(config=decoder_config)
        self.lm_head = nn.Linear(decoder_config.hidden_size, self.vocab_size)
        # Adjust weights
        #self.initialize_decoder_weights()

    # def initialize_decoder_weights(self):
    #     for name, param in self.decoder.named_parameters():
    #         if "cross_attention" in name:
    #             # Random initialization for cross-attention layers
    #             if param.requires_grad:
    #                 nn.init.xavier_uniform_(param.data)
    #         else:
    #             # Use pre-trained weights from ParsBERT
    #             param.data.copy_(self.encoder.state_dict().get(name, param.data))

    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, decoder_input_ids, decoder_attention_mask):
        # Encoder: Encode the input sequence
        encoder_outputs = self.encoder(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
        encoded_sequence = encoder_outputs.last_hidden_state

        # Decoder: Decode the sequence conditioned on the encoder outputs
        decoder_outputs = self.decoder(
            input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
            attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
            encoder_hidden_states=encoded_sequence,
            encoder_attention_mask=attention_mask,
        )

        logits = self.lm_head(decoder_outputs.last_hidden_state)
        return logits

training phase:
def train_model(model,tokenizer, input_texts, target_summaries):
    optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
    padding_idx = tokenizer.pad_token_id
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=padding_idx)
    # Create PyTorch DataLoader
    train_data = list(zip(input_texts, target_summaries))
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
    for epoch in range(EPOCH):
        model.train()
        total=len(train_loader)
        index=0
        for batch in train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Tokenize and convert to tensors
            input_texts, target_texts = batch
            inputs = encode_batch(input_texts, tokenizer)
            targets = encode_batch(target_texts, tokenizer)

            input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
            attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask']
            decoder_input_ids = targets['input_ids']
            decoder_attention_mask = targets['attention_mask']

            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(
                input_ids=input_ids,
                attention_mask=attention_mask,
                decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
                decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask
            )

            logits = outputs
            labels = decoder_input_ids
            logits=logits.view(-1, logits.size(-1))
            loss = loss_fn(logits, labels.view(-1))
            loss.backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
            optimizer.step()
            index+=1
            print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}, Total Batches:{total} ,Batch:{index}, Loss: {loss.item()}")
            
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model.model")

prediction phase:
def evaluate_model(model, tokenizer, test_texts, reference_summaries):
    #model.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODEL_PATH))
    model.eval()
    rou = Rouge()

    predictions = []

    for text in test_texts:
        # Tokenize the input text
        inputs = tokenizer(
            text,
            return_tensors="pt",
            max_length=512,
            truncation=True,
            padding="max_length",
        )

        # Generate decoder inputs (start with <sos> token)
        decoder_input_ids = torch.tensor([[tokenizer.cls_token_id]])
        decoder_attention_mask = torch.ones_like(decoder_input_ids)

        output_tokens = []

        with torch.no_grad():
            for _ in range(50):  # Generate up to 50 tokens
                logits = model(
                    input_ids=inputs["input_ids"],
                    attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"],
                    decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
                    decoder_attention_mask=decoder_attention_mask,
                )
                # Get the token with the highest probability
                next_token = torch.argmax(logits[:, -1, :], dim=-1)
                if (
                    next_token.item() == tokenizer.sep_token_id
                ):  # Stop if end-of-sequence token is generated
                    break
                output_tokens.append(next_token.item())

                # Update decoder inputs
                decoder_input_ids = torch.cat(
                    [decoder_input_ids, next_token.unsqueeze(0)], dim=1
                )
                decoder_attention_mask = torch.ones_like(decoder_input_ids)

        # Decode the generated tokens into text
        prediction = tokenizer.decode(output_tokens, skip_special_tokens=True)
        predictions.append(prediction)

    # Compute ROUGE scores
    results = rou.get_scores(predictions, reference_summaries, avg=True)

    return results, predictions


It generate a repetitive list of tokens as output like [2,2,2,2,.....]

Hey! Are you restricted to a own Bert2Bert model? If not you could use the Seq2SeqTrainer of HuggingFace with a EncoderDecoderModel.from_encoder_decoder_pretrained("HooshvareLab/bert-base-parsbert-uncased", "HooshvareLab/bert-base-parsbert-uncased")
See this notebook for more information: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WIk2bxglElfZewOHboPFNj8H44_VAyKE?usp=sharing#scrollTo=tS0UndNoQh8t

thank you so much, I want to implement it from scratch. can you help me? I so that notebook before.

Ok, I can help with that. I'll look into your code tomorrow/on the weekend :)
